# Help to Capture a Date Based on Opp Stage Logic

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow rule set to update a date field on the opportunity when the stage = "Initiation" and it is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria.

The Opp Stages are as follows: Unvetted, Initiation, Discovery & Presentation.

We'd like to update the WFR so that if initiation date is blank and moves to Discovery we'll capture the date of TODAY in the initiation Date field. If initiation date is NOT blank and moves to Discovery do NOT update the initiation Date field.

Can someone help? Do I need to create 2 separate workflow rules?

Comment: Your current workflow rule has criteria if the stage changes to Initiation? Should the date be updated if it changes to Initiation and the date is already set? I think what you might want is something like criteria formula: ISCHANGED(StageName) && (ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Initiation") || (ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Discovery") && ISBLANK(Initiation_Date__c)))